# How to use pdb to automatically add breakpoints when functions enter and return

Tags: python-3.x, pdb, pexpect

This is an example
I created a pdb_torch_load.py as follows:

```
import torch
PATH = './resnet18-f37072fd.pth'
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
torch.load(PATH)
```

Another pexpect_test.py for simulating command line interaction is as follows:

```
import pexpect

# pexpect.spawnu does not work on windows
c = pexpect.spawnu('python3 pdb_torch_load.py',timeout=60)
c .logfile = open("./pdb_torch_load.log", "w")

while True:
    c.expect_exact('Pdb')
    c.sendline('s')
    c.expect_exact('Pdb')
    c.sendline('w')
```

This way I can get all the function calls and stack traces executed line by line during deserialization of the pth file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsB3f.png)

But unfortunately, this is too inefficient, and it may take up to several hours to get a complete row of torch.load results

I tried pexpect not to immediately write to the log file to reduce the number of I/O, but it has little effect on the overall time consumption.

```
import pexpect

# pexpect.spawnu does not work on windows
c = pexpect.spawnu('python3 pdb_torch_load.py',timeout=60)
result = ''
while True:
        try:
            c.expect_exact('Pdb')
            c.sendline('s')
            result += c.before + c.after
            c.expect_exact('Pdb')
            c.sendline('w')
            result += c.before + c.after
```

Because the stack trace is repeated inside the function during runtime it is not needed. So I want to try to reduce the number of single-step debugging by only breaking point when the function enters and returns, I don't know if this idea is effective or can be achieved